# Прошу помочь с лемматизацией столбца с помощью библиотеки natasha

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, natasha

Прошу вашей помощи:
есть столбец `df['cleaned_review']` с обратной связью от клиента, хочу его лемматизировать с помощью библиотеки natasha и сохранить в столбец `df['lemmatized']`

Пробовал импортировать из библиотеки `from natasha import MorphVocab`

и с помощью кода:

````
   "".join(MorphVocab(word).lemmatize() for word in x.split())) ```

получить, но не работает...ОШИБКА:
``` TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
````

По самому тесту работоспособности:
на входе "нравится ассортимент, много того, что не найде...", избавился от пунктуации, привел к нижнему регистру, а также избавился от stopwords ... на выходе хочу получить что то вроде "ассортимент найти другой магазин..."

Пробовал вариант:

````
   text = str(text) ```

где фидбек клиентов превратил в список.. и с помощью кода  
```from natasha import MorphVocab  
   morph_vocab = MorphVocab()  
   for token in doc.tokens:
       token.lemmatize(morph_vocab)  

   {_.text: _.lemma for _ in doc.tokens} ``` 

на выходе получаю  

```{'[': '[', 
  "'": "'",  
 'ангаре': 'ангар', 
 'нравится': 'нравиться', 
 'магазин': 'магазин',  
 'большой': 'большой',  
 'навигационнопонятный': 'навигационнопонятный',... ```

 Только вот хотелось бы оставить/сохранить все в новом столбце... –
````

Comment: Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: @Сергей привет! на входе "нравится ассортимент, много того, что не найде...", избавился от пунктуации, привел к нижнему регистру, а также избавился от stopwords ... на входе хочу получить что то вроде "ассортимент найти другой магазин..."

Comment: @Сергей также пробовал 
`text = df['cleaned_review'].tolist()`
`text = str(text)`
где фидбек клиентов превратил в список.. и с помощью кода
`from natasha import MorphVocab`
`morph_vocab = MorphVocab()`
`for token in doc.tokens:`
    `token.lemmatize(morph_vocab)`
`{_.text: _.lemma for _ in doc.tokens}`
на выходе получаю 
`{'[': '[',
 "'": "'",
 'ангаре': 'ангар',
 'нравится': 'нравиться',
 'магазин': 'магазин',
 'большой': 'большой',
 'навигационнопонятный': 'навигационнопонятный',... ` и т.д. Только вот хотелось бы оставить/сохранить все в новом столбце...

Comment: Это надо всё писать в вопросе, если относится к нему. Я вижу, что сейчас добавлен текст ошибки. Не знаю эту библиотеку, так что решайте сами, что нужно знающим для ответа вам. Проверьте, что ошибка именно к этой строке выдана.